# How can I pass a result of a program as an argument to cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

Let say there are two separate commands that work well:

```
$x = where.exe cmd.exe
Get-Item -Path $x
```

How can I write the above in one line only, without using variable `x` ? 

I tried the below, but it didn't work

```
Get-Item -Path {where.exe cmd.exe}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-Item -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe)
```